# StopIteration given by a file iteration that uses nested loops

Tags: python, file, file-handling, stopiteration

I'm having some issues with the following block of code.
What I'm trying to do is go through a file line by line, and pull out the lines following a line that contains ".W", until it reaches a line that starts with ".I"

```
with open("cran.all.1400","r") as abstracts:
abstract_list = []
for line in abstracts:
    if (line.startswith(".W")):
        abstract_string = ""
        while not (line.startswith('.I')):
            abstract_string = abstract_string + line
            abstracts.next()
        abstract_list.append(abstract_string)
```

I've encountered the `StopIteration`, and some googling has shown me that this occurs when `.next()` has no value, but I'm not sure how I should be writing this code then.

What I'm unsure of specifically, is how to have the `while` loop continue going through the lines, and have the `for` loop pick up where the `while` loop left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag in the for-loop:

```
with open("cran.all.1400") as abstracts:
    inside = False
    abstract_list = []
    for line in abstracts:
        if line.startswith(".W"):
            inside = True
            abstract_list.append("")
        elif line.startswith(".I"):
            inside = False
        elif inside:
            abstract_list[-1] += line
```

Comment: This worked properly, thank you!

No lines start with ".W" (only lines following) so this works fine.